# Ubuntu Network Performance on over 2k connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I'm using an EC2 c3.8xlarge Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine with over 3k threads simultaneously downloading web pages one after another.

Although this machine should have a 10Gb network performance, I can't get it to perform higher than 10MB/s.

IS there any way I can improve the network speed of my machine?

my /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0
fs.file-max = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65000
net.core.somaxconn = 1024
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 16777216 16777216 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 262144
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2000
net.ipv4.route.flush=1
```